# Playback with AVPlayer produces no sound and no error

Tags: swift, avplayer

I am trying to playback a remote mp3 file by using the following code:

```
import AVFoundation

let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url! as URL)
avPlayer.play()
```

I get no error and no sound. Any hints and tips?

Comment: Could you provide the url?

Comment: use the sample url https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/kukushka.mp3

Comment: Working just fine for me on a playground.

Comment: Any hints for me since it's not working here especially not on a real device. Have you tried it on a real device?

Comment: No. But if it works on a Playground it should work on a device. Volume of the device? ;)

Comment: as loud as possible ...

Comment: What's the error?